# ¿Cómo trabajo simultaneamente el código de una pagina web desde atom?

Tags: git, github

Debemos realizar una página interactiva y somos dos personas encargadas del código. Queremos usar atom. Estamos intentando conerctarlo con GitHub pero no hemos podido me sale

Unable to commit

```
Please tell me who you are.
Run
  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"
to set your account's default identity.
```

Cómo lo puedo solucionar?

Answer (score 1):

te dice que tienes que configurar el nombre de usuario y el mail en la terminal en este caso son los siguientes comandos:

usuario

git config --global user.name "tu nombre de usuario"
para mail

git config --global user.email "tucorreo@dominio.com"